# Wrong column name in table per subclass strategy with abstract class in hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
}

public class ConfiguredBlockEntity : Entity
{
    public virtual ScheduledGreetingEntity ScheduledGreeting { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ConfiguredVariableEditableBlockEntity
    : ConfiguredBlockEntity
{
    public virtual VariableEditableBlockEntity TemplateBlock { get; set; }
}

public class ConfiguredPhoneNumberBlockEntity
    : ConfiguredVariableEditableBlockEntity
{
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the automapping feature of Fluent NHibernate.
This creates the following table structure:

```
create table "BlockEntity" (
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   ExecutionOrder INT null,
   Name NVARCHAR(255) null,
   BlockType NVARCHAR(255) null,
   GreetingId INT null,
   primary key (Id)
);

create table "ConfiguredBlockEntity" (
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   ScheduledGreetingId INT null,
   primary key (Id)
);

create table ConfiguredPhoneNumberBlockEntity (
    ConfiguredVariableEditableBlockId INT not null,
   PhoneNumber NVARCHAR(255) null,
   VariableEditableBlockId INT null,
   primary key (ConfiguredVariableEditableBlockId)
);

alter table ConfiguredPhoneNumberBlockEntity 
    add constraint FK87F9EFC9BB9A4B52 
    foreign key (ConfiguredVariableEditableBlockId) 
    references "ConfiguredBlockEntity";
```

There are some problems with this result:

1. The table `ConfiguredPhoneNumberBlockEntity` has one column that is primary key and foreign key to the base class in one (column `ConfiguredVariableEditableBlockId`. This looks strange and doesn't conform to how I normally design my tables. If I would have designed the table by hand, it would have an `Id` column that is the PK and an `ConfiguredBlockId` columnt that is the FK. **Can I change this somehow with fluent or automapping?**
2. The PK/FK column is named `ConfiguredVariableEditableBlockId`, but there exists no table `ConfiguredVariableEditableBlock`, because it was an abstract base class and its property has been incorporated into `ConfiguredPhoneNumberBlockEntity` table. This column references the table `ConfiguredBlockEntity` and thus should be named accordingly. **How to fix this in fluent or automapping?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. an inheritance table doesnt need an extra Id column, its never read alone or by id. Normally its joined with the baseclass-table. Therefor FNH defaults to this design. You can enforce your design for example with FluentMappings with a hidden Property Id as Readonly (additional work for no value).
2. ```
   class MyJoinedSubclassConvention : IJoinedSubclassConvention,
                                      IJoinedSubclassConventionAcceptance
   {
       public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IJoinedSubclassInspector> criteria)
       {
           criteria.Expect(x => x.Name == "ConfiguredPhoneNumberBlockEntity");
       }

       public void Apply(IJoinedSubclassInstance instance)
       {
           instance.Key.Column("baseclassId");
       }
   }
   ```

Edit: or more general

```
class MyJoinedSubclassConvention : IJoinedSubclassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IJoinedSubclassInstance instance)
    {
        Type basetype = instance.Extends;
        while (basetype.IsAbstract)
        {
            basetype = basetype.BaseType;
        }
        instance.Key.Column(basetype.Name + "Id");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About 1: I guess you are right. About 2: That is extremely specific. Isn't there a better way? Or is this a bug in NHibernate?

Comment: It might look good, but it isn't working. Calling instance.Key.Column has no effect, because the key already has a user defined column and thus returns immediately, without changing the column name :(

Comment: of course, user defined is always prefered. you havent specified that you have supplied a custom KeyColumn before. Then you can just specify the name there or remove your custom keycolumn

Comment: Problem is, I haven't specified that name anywhere... It is set by AutoMapping I guess.

Comment: automapping only sets default values, which are overridden by conventions and overridden by overrides in that order, there must be another problem. see instance.Key.Columns.First().Name after  instance.Key.Column(basetype.Name + "Id");

Comment: Oh my ... Thanks for clarifying this! I indeed had a convention in place that was the root of all my problems: `ForeignKey.Format((me, t) => (me != null ? me.Name : t.Name) + "Id")`... When I remove that, I don't even need the code suggested by you. Everything works as expected - with the exception of the names of the foreign keys. Thanks again!